# How to use different validation function onSubmit in react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-final-form

Example - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-level-validation-example-jlqfx?fontsize=14

I have a form with age which is a required numerical field. I want to run two different validations

1. When the user enters a input, it should validate if the entry is a number. If the user leaves it empty, no error should be surfaced
2. When the user clicks submit, it should validate that the entry is not empty AND it's a number.

Basically, the non-empty validation should only run on submit. How do I achieve this using react-final-form

Answer (score 4):

For submission only errors, put your validation logic directly in `onSubmit`. If `onSubmit` returns an object of errors (or a promise that resolves in one), those will be considered "submit errors", and they will appear in `meta.submitError` for any field that has one. So notice how you need to check both `meta.error` and `meta.submitError` when displaying the errors.

[image: Edit React Final Form - Field-Level Validation Example]

Comment: That worked. Thanks! But now I am facing another problem. The `onSubmit` validation is not running if there are already errors on the page. I guess handleSubmit only triggers when there are no errors on the form? How do I run the onSubmit validation regardless of the existing errors?

Comment: Interesting. That's a use case I had not yet seen. Maybe warnings?

https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#field-warnings